# using is_paged for hiding image on posts

Tags: posts, pagination, paged

In my posts I'm using `<!--nextpage-->` in order to paginate specific blog posts, which works fine. But my issue is that the featured image shows in the post header for each page.

I've tried using `!is_paged` but it's not working and I read that it doesn't work for posts using `<!--nextpage-->`

The code I'm using:

```php
if (isset($props['featured_in_head'])) {
  if ( !is_paged() ){
    $props['featured'] = $props['featured_in_head'];
  }
}
```

I've noticed on the sub-pages of this one post that my body has the classes of `single-paged-2` or `paged-2`, but it doesn't look like it has just the paged class, so if there's a way to hide `.featured` via CSS I could just do that

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read that it doesn't work for posts using `<!--nextpage-->`

Not necessarily, but basically, if the current URL ends with `/page/<number>` as in `https://example.com/page/2/` and `https://example.com/category/foo/page/2/`, then `is_paged()` would work, i.e. it returns `true` on page 2, 3, etc.

But for singular posts with a page break, i.e. the `<!--nextpage-->` tag, where the URL normally ends with `/<number>` as in `https://example.com/hello-world/2/`, then `is_paged()` would return a `false`.

However, you can use `get_query_var( 'page' )` (or the global `$page` variable) to get the page number and then render the featured image only if the page number is 1 or < 2.

So for example, just replace the `!is_paged()` in your `if` with `(int) get_query_var( 'page' ) < 2`, and then that image would no longer appear on page 2, 3 and so on.

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you so much. The confusion is cleared up now for sure, but I wasn't even aware of the get_query_var option so that's another tool in my belt now. Thanks!